# Interraccion con facebook y twitter

Tags: php, facebook, twitter-api, facebook-api

Necesito hacer un sistema donde dada una url de una noticia por ej: 
www.dominiodiario.com/2016/09/01/titulo-noticia, poder saber las interacciones que tuvo en facebook y twitter esa noticia.

Se que de los post de facebook se puede obtener los likes y los shares, pero nose como llegar al post desde la url, si hay alguna forma.

Gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a SOes, de pura o simple casualidad has intentado algo?

Con respecto a **facebook**:

> ## Post /{post-id}
>
> An individual entry in a profile's feed. The profile could be a user, page, app, or group.
> **Traducción:**
> Una entrada individual del feed de un perfil. El perfil podría ser usuario, página, app o grupo.

*Extraído de:* https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post

Con respecto a **twitter**:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

Lo que se me ocurre para solucionar esto es poder guardar el ID del post (twitter y facebook) junto con la URL en tu base de datos y a raíz de ello jugar con las APIs mencionada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me pondre a trabajar en base a tu respuesta!

Comment: ¿Podrías aceptarla por favor? Así ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio en base a % de preguntas resueltas :D